# Does apple actually name classes as WTF?

Tags: development

In the screenshot below, find the stack trace and look at the last stack(s). Is that just a programmers (@Apple) frustration or is there any acronym? I tried looking for some meaningful [values](http://www.acronymfinder.com/WTF.html)
[image]

Comment: What screenshot? There isn't any.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that.

Comment: They do on the iPhone, not sure about the Mac though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **WTF** stands for **Web Template Framework**, which is a part of **WebKit**.